# C++ how to replace type in variadic template by its index

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

How can I replace 1 type from variadic template by its index?
For example I have:

```
//-------------static_list-------------
template<class ...Elements>
struct static_list {};

struct execute_command<index, static_list<Commands...>> {
    static constexpr int value = execute_s<index + 1, static_list<Commands...>>::value;
}
```

and I want to rewrite it so in Commands it will replace type at for example index 5 with type `variable<0, 0>` like this:

```
struct execute_command<false, true, false, false, false, index, static_list<Commands...>> {
    static constexpr int value = execute_s<index + 1, static_list_replace<5, variable<0, 0>, Commands...>>::value;
}
```

I have tried it many different ways but nothing was working. For example:

```
//-------------static_list_replace-------------
template<std::size_t N, typename T, typename Tuple, class IndexSequence>
struct static_list_replace;

template<std::size_t N, typename T, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Idx>
struct static_list_replace<N, T, Tuple, std::index_sequence<Idx ...>> {
    using type = std::tuple<std::conditional_t<N == Idx, T, std::tuple_element_t<N, Tuple>>...>;
};
```

or

```
namespace detail {
    template<std::size_t N, typename T, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Idx>
    auto replace(std::index_sequence<Idx...>) ->
        std::tuple<std::conditional_t<N == Idx,
        T,
        std::tuple_element_t<N, Tuple>>...>;
}

template <std::size_t N, typename T, typename... Args>
using Replace = decltype(detail::replace<N, T, std::tuple<Args...>>
    (std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{}));
```

or I tried to get beginnig of the list and end without the one element and then pack it like `static_list<list_beginning<index, Commands...>, element, list_ending<index, Commands...>>>`

Nothing worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose there are many ways...

For example, given an helper class as `slrh` (Static List Replace Helper)

```
template <std::size_t, typename...>
struct slrh;

template <std::size_t N, typename R, std::size_t ... Is, typename ... Ts>
struct slrh<N, R, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...>
 { using type = static_list<std::conditional_t<(N == Is), R, Ts>...>; };
```

your `static_list_replace` can be simply written as follows

```
template <std::size_t, typename R, typename SL>
struct static_list_replace;

template <std::size_t N, typename R, typename ... Ts>
struct static_list_replace<N, R, static_list<Ts...>>
   : public slrh<N, R, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>, Ts...>
 { };
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename ...>
struct static_list
 { };

template <std::size_t, typename...>
struct slrh;

template <std::size_t N, typename R, std::size_t ... Is, typename ... Ts>
struct slrh<N, R, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...>
 { using type = static_list<std::conditional_t<(N == Is), R, Ts>...>; };

template <std::size_t, typename R, typename SL>
struct static_list_replace;

template <std::size_t N, typename R, typename ... Ts>
struct static_list_replace<N, R, static_list<Ts...>>
   : public slrh<N, R, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>, Ts...>
 { };

template <int...>
struct variable
 { };

int main()
 {
   using T1 = static_list<char, short, int, long, long long>;
   using T2 = static_list<char, short, char, long, long long>;
   using T3 = typename static_list_replace<2u, char, T1>::type;

   using T4 = static_list_replace<4, variable<16, 16>,
                static_list<char, short, int, long, long long>>::type;
   using T5 = static_list<char, short, int, long, variable<16, 16>>;

   static_assert( std::is_same_v<T2, T3> );
   static_assert( std::is_same_v<T4, T5> );
 }
```

Comment: when I write it like this:
`template <int index, typename ...Commands>
struct execute_command<false, true, false, false, false, index, static_list<Commands...>> {
 static constexpr int value = execute_s<index + 1, static_list_replace<4, variable<16, 16>, static_list<Commands...>>::type>::value;
};`
it gives me an error: slrh<things inside>::type : illegal use of this type as an expression.
And exactly this error I got with all the other implementations, what does it mean?

Comment: @Rikib161999 - I've integrated the full example with a substitution with `variable<16, 16>`. It works. Sorry but without full (not) compiling example, I can't imagine where your problem is.

Comment: I dont know why the use type is not worknig for me so I just did it with int value and cycle it and it is now working
Thanks a lot for your help! Appreciate it!